# os.path.normpath() returns False in ubuntu when compare two path in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to compare two path in window platform it working fine but in ubuntu it returns False.

This is what I have done so far.

```
target_dirs = ['/folder_a/folder_b/folder_c/']

os.path.normpath('/folder_a/folder_b/folder_c/') in target_dirs
```

The out put is False. But It should be True because the both path is same. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: `normpath` will strip the trailing slash so you're comparing `'/a/b/c'` to `'/a/b/c/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs for [os.path.normpath(path)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath)

Normalize a pathname by collapsing redundant separators and up-level references so that A//B, A/B/, A/./B and A/foo/../B all become A/B. This string manipulation may change the meaning of a path that contains symbolic links.

```
import os

target_dirs = map(os.path.normpath, ['/folder_a/folder_b/folder_c/'])

print(os.path.normpath('/folder_a/folder_b/folder_c/') in target_dirs)
```

Thus, you'll need to apply `normpath` to both sides of the comparison.